# Faucet adapter not fitting /screwing in

Tags: faucet, kitchen-sink, adapter

I am trying to attach a faucet adapter to my kitchen sink to allow me to add a touch-less adapter.  I made some mistakes on sizes and finally arrives at M16 female (*on faucet side*) to M22 male (*for touch-less adapter side*).

The adapter size seems close to the size needed on the faucet diameter size, but  when I try to screw it in it manages to go in a little but then does not screw in.

Am I am making a mistake on size still or my adapter has bad threads?

M16 female to M24 male adapter.
[image]

The adapter with M24 size.
[image]

The faucet thread.
[image]

Comment: the bottom picture shows what appears to be damaged thread

Comment: Are you sure it is a metric thread? When I have hardware that starts but only goes on a turn then gets tight that indicates the wrong thread pitch

Comment: Jsotola the thread you refer to if o the tap. The thread does work for the installing the aerator so even it is damaged, it works. Thanks!

Comment: @Ed Beal thanks for the hint. I did not know about types of threads for faucets. From what you are saying that might be an issue. This is what I am likely experiencing. Can you lease point to any types of threads? I found this one. https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.engineeringtoolbox.com/amp/metric-threads-d_777.html

Comment: Yes that is the idea in the US we have corse and fine  for example a 1/2” bolt is normally 1/4-20 but there is a fine version 1/4-28. I believe there may be a “British” pipe thread I think I have read about that is used in the UK but not sure, if you have a plumbing and electric specialty shop that’s where I go the cost may be slightly higher but they will know what the thread is and probably have one for reasonable price. Take a photo with a measuring tape next to the pipe snd show them the photo that may be enough information to get the correct size.

Comment: Thank you @EdBeal very much